# Header and BottomTabNavigator gets double height when reloading in React-Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

I have been struggling with this for days now and can't find a solution so all help is welcome. When reloading the app my **BottomTabBar** as well as the **Header** gets **increased height**. When the app has **finished reloading** it goes to **normal**, but this happens on each reload.

I have tried updating React-Native to 0.72.3 as well as react-navigation and also now create a blank project to face the same issue. I will attach an image of the behavior where the one to the **left** is **reloading** and the one to the **right** when it is **done**.

Note that I have tried on different Android emulators (<10) and all have the same problem.

**App.tsx**

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>Settings!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image: Problem]

Comment: Debugging suggestion, which might help with nothing: change the backgroundColor of the `Tab.Navigator` to something like red, so if the entire bottom bar is red, then the problem is with the Tab.Navigator styles, which might be using something like % or flex for its height. If the Tab.Navigator is partially red and partially white, then there's another component below the Tab.Navigator which is causing this problem.

Comment: I think debugging can help you better. Alongside the above comment, Open the Flipper, inspect the elements, and check the styles. I'm sure you can find out what is the reason for this issue.

Comment: But if you think you can't, create a Github repo for reproducing this issue, ping me and then I'll check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One working solution is to wrap the NavigationContainer in `SafeAreaProvider`

```
<SafeAreaProvider>
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
</SafeAreaProvider>
```

[gif: reloading in android](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wv745.gif)

Answer (score 0):

You can use SafeAreaView by wrapping it inside the navigation container

```js
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';

function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Tab.Navigator>
          <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
          <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={SettingsScreen} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </SafeAreaView>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

@Quantal you need to set height to bottom tabs navigator. You can set style with the help of **tabBarStyle** property.

```html
 <BottomTabs.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Your initial route name"
    screenOptions={({ route, navigation }) => ({
    tabBarHideOnKeyboard: Platform.OS !== 'ios',
    headerShown: false,
    tabBarStyle: { height: 70, backgroundColor: Theme.white, },
    tabBarItemStyle: { padding: 10, height: 70},
 >
 </BottomTabs.Navigator>
```